# Case insensitive text() comparison with DOMdocument?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

How can I do a case insensitive comparison on the keyword's appearance in my content in the script below?

If I use this...

```
$keyword = strtolower(rseo_getKeyword($post));

$nodes = $x->query("//text()[
    contains(
    translate(.,'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
                '$keyword')
```

The replacement is only made on keyword matches within the content that is already lowercase. It does not appear to be doing a case insensitive lookup.

```
    $keyword = rseo_getKeyword($post);
    $content = $postarray['post_content']; //error: Empty string supplied in loadHTML() when I use this.
    //$content = "this is a test phrase";
    @$d = new DOMDocument();
    @$d->loadHTML($content);
    @$x = new DOMXpath($d);
    @$nodes = $x->query("//text()[contains(.,'$keyword') 
        and not(ancestor::h1) 
        and not(ancestor::h2) 
        and not(ancestor::h3) 
        and not(ancestor::h4) 
        and not(ancestor::h5) 
        and not(ancestor::h6)]");
    if ($nodes && $nodes->length) {
        $node = $nodes->item(0);
        // Split just before the keyword
        $keynode = $node->splitText(strpos($node->textContent, $keyword));
        // Split after the keyword
        $node->nextSibling->splitText(strlen($keyword));
        // Replace keyword with <b>keyword</b>
        $replacement = $d->createElement('b', $keynode->textContent);
        $keynode->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $keynode);
    }
    echo $d->saveHTML();die;
```

Comment: Pretty much duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625986/how-can-i-use-xpath-to-perform-a-case-insensitive-search-and-support-non-english

Comment: @rik, I've attempted to substitute the translate routing into my xquery (and updated my question with that info) but when I do, the replacement is not made at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [case insensitive xpath searching in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238989/case-insensitive-xpath-searching-in-php/3240155#3240155)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//text()
    [contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                        'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),                 
              '$keyword') 
    ]
```

**The correct expression must test if the lowercased text contains** *the lowercased keyword*:

```
//text()
    [contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                          'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),                 
              translate('$keyword','ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                   'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz')                 
              ) 
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `text()` function returns all text node children of the context node. When you call it as a parameter to `translate()`, the *context node is a text node* and so will have no text node children. Instead, use `.` to properly select the context node itself as you really want.

Replace your try:

```
contains(translate(text(), 'ABC…
```

with

```
contains(translate(., 'ABC…
```

Comment: I've changed it in my question, but I'm still doing something wrong. I'm only getting matches when the keyword is lowercase within the content.

Comment: @Scott B, maybe provide a reproducible example and we can move from there. Upper/lower/MixEd case keywords in the content work fine with the short snippet of HTML I used just to check the notes above.