# XPATH: Check if a xml node contains specific characters or strings

Tags: c#, xml, string, xpath, contains

Imagine this XML file (sorry for sick example!!)

```
<DOC>
<Test>
    <Name>1 vs 100 Pre pre History</Name>
    <Type>Dinasors</Type>
</Test>

<Test>
    <Name> 1 vs 100 Post moderns</Name>
    <Type>Aliens</Type>
</Test>
</Doc>
```

The idea is returning the Type value, By checking if Name node contains a specific character or string. For example I want a XPath Query like:

```
/Doc//Test[contains "Pre" and "History" and 1]/Type
```

That is check if Test contains "Pre" and "History" and number 1, What will be the xpath query? Alo I like this query to not be CASE SENSITIVE.

Thanks.

Comment: Are we talking Xpath 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work (haven't tested it):

```
/Doc//Test[contains(Name,'Pre') and contains(Name,'History') and contains(Name,1)]/Type
```

However that is case sensitive. If you want it case insensitive, then you may want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625986/how-can-i-use-xpath-to-perform-a-case-insensitive-search-and-support-non-english) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt): you must use `translate` to convert your `Name` to lower-case (or upper-case) and then match.

Comment: +1 Correct, but do note tha `//` operator is not needed. Also it could be reduce to `/Doc/Test[Name[contains(.,'Pre')][contains(.,'History'][contains(.,'1')]]/Type`

Answer (score 0):

it works when:

```
/Doc//Test[contains(Name,'Pre')][contains(Name,'History')][contains(Name,1)]/Type;
```