# case insensitive search in xpath 1

Tags: php, regex, xpath, case-insensitive

I am searching through HTML for "myfunc". However, the capitalization is uncertain. Unfortunately, PHP works with XPath 1 so all searches are case-sensitive.

How can I update the following code to search for "myfunc", "MyFunc", "myFunc", etc.?

```
foreach($domxpath->query('//*[@*[contains(.,"myfunc")]]') as $node) {
```

The following doesn't work. Nor did my attempt at implementing [a translate() work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625986/how-can-i-use-xpath-to-perform-a-case-insensitive-search-and-support-non-english).

```
foreach($domxpath->query('//*[@*[matches(.,"[mM][yY][fF][uU][nN][cC]")]]') as $node) {
```

If regex is not possible, how could I search on an array of strings (i.e. "myfunc", "MyFunc", "myFunc", etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

matches is a XPath 2 function, in XPath 1 you have to use translate to convert it to a normalized case:

```
 //*[@*[contains(translate(., "MYFUNC", "myfunc"),"myfunc")]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [case-insentitive option](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags) for matches:

```
foreach($domxpath->query('//*[@*[matches(.,"myfunc","i")]]') as $node) {
```

To compare a sequence of values, just use `=` to do a node set comparison:

```
(. = ("myfunc", "MyFunc", "myFunc"))
```

will return true if anything in the left sequence anything in the right sequence. From [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

> If both objects to be compared are node-sets, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-values of the two nodes is true.